# How to reference local Gradle project from Maven build as dependency?

Tags: maven, gradle, dependencies

I have several Gradle library projects and main Ant spring web-app project (historically). I'd like to replace Ant with Maven for main project while keeping existing Gradle projects nature.

Is it possible to refer local Gradle projects from pom.xml as local dependencies of Maven project?

Search readily gives me the opposite - "how to refer maven projects from gradle builds", but not my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle always builds locally build/libs (or distributions); the only easy way to share the build dependencies between completely different projects is 'as maven repository dependencies'

in your case the options are

1. Work Local Builds only
   add the maven plugin to the gradle builds - do local install
   and refer them in the maven build locally.
2. Build Anywhere
   Your Gradle builds publish artefacts to your local nexus
   and you refer them properly in your dependencies

--
Gradle by default does not have 'maven install'; it can be added using the maven plugin see - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#header.

Comment: The link even shows, that the `maven` plugin is deprecated and should not be used. Instead you should install and setup the `maven-publish` plugin to use its task `publishToMavenLocal`. Then add the projects as dependencies in the `pom` files of your Maven projects.

Comment: agree for the maven-publish